# Why do the sprites in my new scene shrink?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

I tried creating a scene by going under the Resource tab and selecting the Sprite Kit Scene. By doing that I get a .sks file, which I do not want to use. I like creating scenes using the traditional .h and .m files.

So, I go under Source > Cocoa Touch Class > Subclass of SKScene.
This helps me create the .h and .m files. When I add code to this scene to add some sprites, the sprites do get added to the screen and react to touches the same way, but they're not of the same size that I created them. I mean, if I imported the same sprite in "GameScene" they would be of the size that the image is. But when I do this in the new scene, they shrink.

Where am I going wrong here? Is it the way that I am creating the scene? Or is there some code that I need to add for the sprites to be of the same size as in the image from which they are imported?

Comment: If you are unarchiving the scene from an sks file then check it's size. Check what the scene's `size` and `scaleMode` are set to.

Comment: No, I am not unarchiving from an SKS file. I am directly adding the sprites through code in the .m file.

Comment: Can you print the scene's and view's frames to compare?

Comment: in the constructor of the scene set scene.size = view.bounds.size;  I am betting that your scene size is not the same as your view size.  A quick NSLog run through should give you the info you need to confirm